# Event-based extension of query builder in Doctrine repository

Tags: php, events, doctrine, doctrine-orm, dql

I have a Doctrine entity `Page` which is loaded by module `Foo`. The page is a nested set provided by the [Gedmo Doctrine Extension](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions). The module `Bar` has another model `Metadata`, 1:1 related to a page. I would like to join the metadata directly when `Foo` loads the tree.

So inside module `Foo`:

```
$em->getRepository('My\Entity\Page')->getRootNodes();
```

This loads a collection of pages, but I'd like to have the metadata available directly. Because I trigger an event after loading the nodes, all modules can subscribe to this event and use the pages for whatever they want (in this case, meta data is required for a navigation structure, but navigation has nothing to do with module `Foo`, only with `Bar`).

The system must be kept modular, so `Page` has no dependency on `Metadata`. Is it somehow possible `Bar` listens to an event, building the query inside the repository? Then it adds an additional join to load the metadata of each page.

```
function getCalledOnEventTrigger($event)
{
    $q = $event->getQueryObject();
    $q->leftJoin('some join expression');
    // Query now joins metadata as well
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finished this by using the Zend\EventManager I inject into my custom repository. This works, but still doesn't work well because Doctrine must be aware of all relations, so the query I actually want to perform with the definitions in place, is impossible to execute. I solved it by adding the definitions nonetheless.